# phpmyadmin run stored procedures

Tags: php, sql, procedure

Hey I'm writing a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin. I created one to search a database:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', search ,'%');
```

The problem here is this: When I run it, it only returns 1 row, but it should return at least 3 when I input a search string. I also tried this part `('%', search ,'%');` with dots
('%'. search .'%'), but this gives me an SQL syntax error. What is the problem here? I run this procedure in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: What is "search"? is it a param? Provide full text of your procedure -- curenntly it's not clearly enough.

Comment: Er... procedures do not return anything by definition. What are you trying to do? What's your full code?

Comment: The statement runs like a charm; however, keep in mind that a stored procedure returns usually only one value - unless you return a cursor that might cover a larger result set.

Comment: Can you provide the records that you're expecting to be returned and the search term?  That would provide insight to whether or not your concat function is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Well i have a database with car names. For example:
car
car1
car2
car3
The search is a parameter that user wanna search. I would like to return all cars, not only  car. Ful code in phpmyadmin:
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', search ,'%');
END